Want to complain about a gratuitous personal attack on the main site
I have been accused of anti-Semitism:

I’m voting to close this question because it is an excuse to link to an anti-semitic post.

If the commenter is a mind-reader, he/she should post his/her qualifications.
As it stands, the user has made a vicious "antisemitism" accusation.


The question is now on ELL / 2. It's not really "vicious" / 3. This is best raised in a support ticket or flagged for mod attention, rather than posted publicly


You should flag the comment. It's not the done thing to call out an individual comment on Meta, since comments are ephemeral and can actually be deleted by flagging.

It appears to me that the post is ambiguous and could be anti- or pro-Semitic. The headline screenshot comes from the Daily Telegraph [paywalled] but was reported in the London Evening Standard:

A warning by the Government’s counter-extremism tsar that London’s streets have become a “no-go zone for Jews” during pro-Palestinian protests contains “a huge element” of truth, it was claimed on Friday.
Robin Simcox, the commissioner for countering extremism, said the Government had let extremists go “unchallenged for too long”, allowing some to fester in a “permissive environment for radicalisation”.

The headline shown is not anti-Semitic. An independent official actually used that phrase. Actions of the Metropolitan Police have also come under some scrutiny, resulting in an apology and then a second apology for the poor wording of the first.
The reactions to that headline in the video are likely to be pro-Semitic, expressing  "Has London actually deteriorated that much?!" or even a sarcastic "No shit, Sherlock!" agreeing that London is a no-go zone.
I've deleted the comments on that basis. I can't do anything about the comments as they appear on ELL but you should flag them. Comments will be deleted automatically when a threshold number of flags is reached.
However, the current situation of Jews in London is a hot topic, and (even if you are not being anti-Semitic) you should take care to find examples which are unlikely to be controversial. This is especially the case where your premise might be flawed, when members of the community might hold that you have posted a specious question which was asked only to present the example. In this present case, none of the pronunciations of shit exhibited a tense vowel as you asserted. You should have found other examples, including having consulted pronouncing dictionaries like Collins.

the gratuitous accusation is still there  1
"I’m voting to close this question because it is an excuse to link to an anti-semitic post."
that is YOUR assertion (that it is not tense) one poster asked if I was hearing the "sheet" vowel (the short version) which is tense enough.

The comments on ELU have been deleted, and were when I said I had done that. You may need to refresh the page. With regard to tenseness and sheet, you could have said that that's what you were hearing, and compared it to a pronouncing dictionary: sheet certainly isn't what's in the video.

As of now IT IS NOT DELETED !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/351263/do-some-brits-pronounce-shit-with-a-tense-vowel  1
"I’m voting to close this question because it is an excuse to link to an anti-semitic post. – "

See my answer: "I can't do anything about the comments as they appear on ELL but you should flag them. Comments will be deleted automatically when a threshold number of flags is reached."

I didn't dump it there, nor did I vote to close it. Moderators on any site can only do so much. If you are unhappy about another SE site, you need to flag things there for that site's mod team.

How come some mods tell users to call them out on Meta specifically?
